# Can I ask a question about what episodes are on a DVD set?

Tags: discussion

A DVD set has just been released for a TV series.  This contains 3 DVDs (4 episodes per DVD) with 12 episodes total.  I cannot find any information anywhere on which 12 episodes those are.  This is not for a full season - it's just 12 random episodes.

Can I post this question?  I do not consider this to be a list question since there is a finite number of episodes (12) that I am looking for and there is a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: In theory yes, provided it's not something that could be googled and discovered within ten seconds.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/are-questions-about-dvds-of-movie-tv-shows-on-topic) for a similar answer